# Assign a minimum value for a column in an MS-Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

That is, if the returned value is below a set value, give the assigned minimum value. If this isn't possible without a data-modifying query, does anyone know of any VB function that I could compile and use?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Immediate If function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3), which takes the following format:

```
IIf(expression, truepart, falsepart)
```

For example:

```
SELECT IIf(columnName < setValue, assignedMinimumValue, columnName) AS columnAlias
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the immediate and working solution